# For loop that stores variable in progressive order

Tags: function, matlab, loops, for-loop

I am trying to work on a matlab script that calculates a 1x1854 matrix called N2. This routine has to be performed 1000 times because each iteration the input data files are different. I am trying to store the matrix N2 in progressive order for each iteration, like N2_1, N2_2 ecc. How should implement that?

```
for ii=1:1000
    file1 = load(['/Users/gianmarcobroilo/Desktop/1000shifts/delays/GRV_JUGR_2021158_1648X35X35001KV03.NEWFES_delay_' num2str(ii) '.TXT']); 

    file2 = load(['/Users/gianmarcobroilo/Desktop/1000shifts/delays/GRV_JUGR_2021158_1648X35K35001KV03.NEWFES_delay_' num2str(ii) '.TXT']); 
%%calculations...
 [N,bind] = elecdensity(omega_new,closestapproach);
% 

 N2_num2str(ii) = N./1e6;

end
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate those variables, change the code line

```
N2_num2str(ii) = N./1e6;
```

to

```
eval(['N2_' num2str(ii) '= ' 'N./1e6']);
```

This might be computational too expensive. Another approach I will use to avoid the usage of the "eval" command is to save the tables in a structure and each field of it will be the matrix (named N_NUMBER). So, the code will be

```
% Generate the struct object
myValues = struct;

% Start the for loops
for ii=1:1000
    file1 = load(['/Users/gianmarcobroilo/Desktop/1000shifts/delays/GRV_JUGR_2021158_1648X35X35001KV03.NEWFES_delay_' num2str(ii) '.TXT']); 

    file2 = load(['/Users/gianmarcobroilo/Desktop/1000shifts/delays/GRV_JUGR_2021158_1648X35K35001KV03.NEWFES_delay_' num2str(ii) '.TXT']); 
%%calculations...
 [N,bind] = elecdensity(omega_new,closestapproach);
% 
 fieldName = ['N2_' num2str(ii)];
 myValues.(fieldName) = N./1e6;

end

% Print the table 54
myValues.N2_54
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That does the job perfectly. Now I wanted to do a single N2 which is the average of all of the 1000 N2. Can I do it with Navg = mean(['N2_' num2str(ii)]) or something like this?

Comment: This is **not** good advice. All resulting vectors are of the same size, there is no reason not to put them in a large (preallocated) matrix. Dynamic variable names are a nightmare, and dynamic struct field names, though not as bad, are very inconvenient as well. This should be `N2(:,ii)=…` or `N2{ii}=…`.

Comment: Thank you. I am having problems now because every even iteration, like N2_2 N2_4 is complex while all the odd ones are double. Any suggestion?